# Modifying the Legend in eps file

Tags: legend

Is it possible to change Legend in an eps file which I have generated using MATLAB. I have not saved its .fig file, otherwise it would have been easy. I am using this file in LaTex.

Comment: What do you want to change? If you want to replace strings you could use package [`psfrag`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psfrag) or [`psfragx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/psfragx).

Comment: want to change text inside the legend

Comment: So try out one of the packages from my first comment. If they do not work, please add a MWE to your question.

Comment: You could try a vector graphics editor, such as Inkscape. Or redo the figure in Matlab, which will probably take less time than when you made the original figure.